# Variable is undefined even though it's a global variable

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to call an API and check to see if a username exists in a database. The API works perfectly and is returning the username correctly. The issue I am having is that I need to define some variables globally to use later.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var deviceID = getUrlVariables()["me"];
$.ajax({
    url: "funcEntity.cfc?method=getUsername&returnformat=json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        deviceID: deviceID
    },
    success: function(result) {
        if(result == 0){
            alert("Proceed to login menu.");
        }
        else{
            username = result;
        }
    }
});
alert(username);
});
```

The result of the API should be the username and should be able to use globally in other functions? Correct? However, I am getting an error saying the variable "username" is undefined.

Comment: Asynchronous in AJAX means it's not immediately finished.

Comment: @dystroy by setting `async: false,` it works correctly. Would this have any issues with any other functions?

Comment: Well, the whole page is simply frozen... It's very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

## You'll have to wait till you get em

That is the problem.

Asynchronous in ajax is **not synchronous**

What you can do is place the relevant bit of code which uses the returned data from the server inside the `success` handler. Or have any callbacks

Comment: That could be a lot of functions. What this is doing is checking to see if the user exists and grabbing the users information at the start of the application.

Comment: you have no other go. But if you can invest your time in deferred objects and promises, then go ahead